# Linux (Ubuntu 12.10) starts up, but the main menu on the left side, and the pictograms at the upper right corner, do not show up

Tags: unity, 12.10

Linux OS (Ubuntu 12.10) starts up (user login, my personal picture of a beautiful Norwegian fjord-landscape fills the background), but **the main menu on the left side**, **and the pictograms** (battery state etc.) at the upper right corner of the screen, **do not show up**. 
This occurred yesterday quite suddenly after six or seven weeks working with Ubuntu 12.10. Then I started in recovery mode and performed a file system check (fsck) but that takes hours and finally a message ¨Sorry Ubuntu has experienced an internal error etc¨ appeared.
**How can I determine what has gone wrong** and eventually, **how can I solve it?** So that I can work again using Ubuntu 12.10 (on a dual-boot system, Intel i7, ASUS P8P67 motherboard).

Comment: Did you happen to install any graphic drivers by chance? I have this same problem on Acer Aspire One 725 with Radeon HD 6290. After installing Catalst drivers (version 12.6) I have same symptoms. Also, when I try to open a window, it doesn't have the borders.

What is your graphic card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GF104 [GeForce GTX 460]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0

Comment: Hi Melon, a GeForce GTX 460 NVidia, I just copied a part of the lshw-listing above. I tried a couple of things (reinstall the nvidia-current driver, install gnome3-desktop, reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity), but the last thing I did, was choosing the (opensource) X.Org X server (Nouveau display driver) in System settings -> Software sources -> Extra drivers. I'm not sure if this caused the problem, but after reboot, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

[SOLVED] choose the (opensource) X.Org X server (Nouveau display driver) in System settings -> Software sources -> Extra drivers. I'm not sure whether this has caused the problem, but after reboot, it worked for me.

Comment: yes but remember this means moving to the open source drivers which in some ways cripple your graphics performance :)